# Are transformed versions of Java's types acceptable as function input?

Tags: discussion, java

In Java, all "basic" input types are immutable with very few tools at our disposal. Some other class that still represent the same value exist and allow us to do more.

In trying to golf Java code, I always check if `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` can help me. In this case, a `StringBuilder` still represents the Java `String` type. They're useful, but very verbose. Can we use them as input parameters directly?

Given the following code:

```
void blah(String s) {
  StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(s);
  // do something super golfy
}
```

May I answer a golfing question with such code?

```
void blah(StringBuilder t) {
  // do something super golfy
}
```

In another instance, the Java array type exists (examples: `String[]`), but in some cases, it might be shorter to use a `java.util.stream.Stream` as input parameter.

Before:

```
void blah(String[]a){
  Stream<String> s = java.util.Arrays.stream(a);
  // do something super golfy
}
```

After:

```
void blah(java.util.Stream<String>s) {
  // do something super golfy
}
```

I guess that the question can be boiled down to:

**May I transform my objects to other representations of the same objects before passing them as input parameters to the golfed function?**

If I have to provide a list of elements I'd like to be found acceptable as input parameters, here is it: (when no package, assume `java.lang`, just like normal Java code)

- basic types (primitives + String + arrays): `String`, `int`, `long`, `double`, `String[]`, `int[]`, etc.
- Mutable/Helper: `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, etc.
- IO: `java.io.Reader`, `java.io.BufferedReader`, `java.io.InputStream`, etc.
- Collections: `Iterable`, `java.util.Iterator`, `java.util.Collection`, and friends.
- Streams: `java.util.stream.Stream`, `java.util.stream.IntStream`, etc.

Comment: [Related reading](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9501/14215)

Comment: To clarify the difference between @Geobits' linked reading and this question: the link is about different *values*, while this question is about different *representations* of the same values, and specifically for Java.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2214/194)

Answer (score 7):

As long as your transformation doesn't add any additional information to the input than what would be present normally (for a `String`, that information would be the length of the string and the sequence of characters that form the string), it should be fine. You should check with challenge authors on specific cases, though, as they may decide that a given transformation would trivialize the challenge too much to be acceptable.